# Как сделать прелоадер?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, только учусь работать с JS, такой вопрос как можно сделать чтобы в прелоадере от времени дня выводилась картинка и текст:
Если пользователь зашел с 00:00- 06:00 Выводится черный фон и надпись доброй ночи(время работы 3 секунды)
Если пользователь зашел с 06:00- 12:00 Выводится желтый фон и надпись доброе утро(время работы 3 секунды)
Если пользователь зашел с 12:00- 18:00 Выводится черный фон и надпись добрый день(время работы 3 секунды)
Если пользователь зашел с 18:00- 23:59 Выводится черный фон и надпись добрый вечер(время работы 3 секунды)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получаете с помощью `getHours()` час и в зависимости от того, к какому промежутку он относится, меняете текст и цвет фона:

```js
let message = '';
let color = '';

let date = new Date();
let hour = date.getHours();

switch(true) {
  case hour >= 0 && hour < 6:
    message = 'Доброй ночи';
    color = 'black';
    break;
  case hour >= 6 && hour < 12:
    message = 'Доброе утро';
    color = 'yellow';
    break;
  case hour >= 12 && hour < 18:
    message = 'Добрый день';
    color = 'green';
    break;
  case hour >= 18 && hour < 24:
    message = 'Добрый вечер';
    color = 'maroon';
    break;
  default:
    message = 'Доброго времени суток';
}

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'preloader';
div.style.backgroundColor = color;
div.innerHTML = '<h1>'+message+'</h1>';

document.body.append(div);
```

```css
.preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  animation: opacity 3s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes opacity {
  80% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
Какой-то контент на сайте
```

Comment: @Sevastopol', можно же просто сделать let hour = date.getHours()+7, например, или -10 :)) И сразу посмотреть =)

Comment: @Sevastopol', :))))

Comment: @Sevastopol' главное не проспать))

Comment: Самому теперь интересно

Comment: Только появился вопрос, а возможно ли цвет заменить на картинку?

Comment: @АлексейРешетило, можно: вместо div.style.backgroundColor пишете div.style.backgroundImage, а в проверке вместо названия цвета указываете путь к картинке в формате "url('_здесь путь к картинке_')"

Comment: Там круто меняется)))